# Calling onload event with more than function call

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this in my html:

```
<body onload='myjavascriptfunction1()'
```

I also want to be able, with the same onload event to call 'myjavascriptfunction2() along with myjavascriptfunction1()'. Please, is this possible?

Comment: On the first line in the first function, call the second function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<body onload='myjavascriptfunction1();myjavascriptfunction2()'>
```

or create a function and then call from that function the other functions you want

```
function myjavascriptfunction1(){
    myjavascriptfunction2();
    myjavascriptfunction3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic OnLoad function

```
<body onload='onLoad()'>

function onLoad(){
    myJSFunction1();
    myJSFunction2();
}
```

But a better way would be to subscribe to the onload event using addEventListener

```
window.addEventListener("load", myJSFunction1, false);
window.addEventListener("load", myJSFunction2, false);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a56Nm/1/)

This keeps your JS separate from your HTML and prevents you from adding the ugly onLoad attribute to the body tag.

Comment: Can you please provide the jsfiddle for `addEventListener()`

Comment: @Suman, why are you insisting on a fiddle? The code is right here, you only have to paste it.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, actully the `onload` event is not triggered with way of 'addEventListener()' at my side.

Comment: hmm in this way, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Attach [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) rather than defining onload events in the markup

```
  document.body.addEventListener("load", do_something(), false);

  function do_something() {
    alert("hello universe");
    //do something here
  }
```

Refer to [Event Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) documentation for more info. If your event listener has to work on multiple browsers like legacy IE's you might have to define other event listeners like `attachEvent`. Libraries like jQuery are handy for these needs as you don't have to worry about browser compatibilities.

Comment: Can you please provide the jsfiddle for this?

Comment: The code you provided is not worked. Please post the answer with tested result.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L48mW/) Check the edited answer. For some reason, using anonymous functions as event listener does not work in JSFiddle. The edited code is a different way of doing the same and it works in JSFiddle

Comment: I think the way you invoked the function `do_something()` in `addEventListener` is invalid, I have never seen before this.